# Pyspark read csv and combine date and time column and filter based on it

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, filter, pyspark

I have about 10,000 csv files containing 14 columns each. They contain data regarding a financial organization, the trade values, date and its time.

Some of the csv files are just headers and have no data in them. I managed to load all the csv files on my local hadoop file system. What I want to achieve is to filter the data to include records occurring only between 9am to 6pm.

How would I achieve this? Im so confused with the lambda and filter and all the stuff exists in the spark-python.

Could you show me how I can filter this and use the filtered data to do other analyses?

P.S, the winter time and summer time also needs to be considered which I was thinking I should have some functions to change the time to UTC format perhaps?

As my concern is about filtering data based on the Time column in my csv file, I have simplified the csvs. lets say:

CSV 1:(Filter.csv)

- ISIN,Currency,Date,Time
- "1","EUR",2018-05-08,07:00
- "2","EUR",2018-05-08,17:00
- "3","EUR",2018-05-08,06:59
- "4","EUR",2018-05-08,17:01

CSV 2:(NoFilter.csv)

- ISIN,Currency,Date,Time
- "1","EUR",2018-05-08,07:01
- "2","EUR",2018-05-08,16:59
- "3","EUR",2018-05-08,10:59
- "4","EUR",2018-05-08,15:01

and my code is:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sqlc = SQLContext(sc)

ehsanLocationFiltered = 'hdfs://localhost:54310/user/oxclo/ehsanDbs/Filter.csv'
ehsanLocationNonFiltered = 'hdfs://localhost:54310/user/oxclo/ehsanDbs/NoFilter.csv'

df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')\
.options(header='true', inferschema='true')\
.load(ehsanLocationNonFiltered)

dfFilter = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')\
.options(header='true', inferschema='true')\
.load(ehsanLocationFiltered)

data = df.rdd
dataFilter = dfFilter.rdd

data.filter(lambda row: row.Time > '07:00' and row.Time < '17:00')
dataFilter.filter(lambda row: row.Time > '07:00' and row.Time < '17:00')

print data.count()
print dataFilter.count()
```

I am expecting to see the data.count returns 4 as all Times are fitting to the range and dataFilter.count returns 0 as there is no matching time.

Thanks!

Comment: post code which you have tried then we can help you better way

Comment: Its done and I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you can use only **'csv'** as the format

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
ehsanLocationFiltered = '/FileStore/tables/stackoverflow.csv'
df = sqlContext.read.format('csv')\
.options(header='true', inferschema='true')\
.load(ehsanLocationFiltered).rdd
result=data.map(lambda row: row.Time > '07:00' and row.Time < '17:00')
result.count()
```

Comment: thanks. I just needed to change:result=data.map(lambda row: row.Time > '07:00' and row.Time < '17:00') to result=df.filter(lambda row: row.Time > '07:00' and row.Time < '17:00')

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out what is the problem with my code! I should have used:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sqlc = SQLContext(sc)

ehsanLocationFiltered = 'hdfs://localhost:54310/user/oxclo/ehsanDbs/Filter.csv'
ehsanLocationNonFiltered = 'hdfs://localhost:54310/user/oxclo/ehsanDbs/NoFilter.csv'

df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')\
   .options(header='true', inferschema='true')\
   .load(ehsanLocationNonFiltered)

dfFilter = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')\
   .options(header='true', inferschema='true')\
   .load(ehsanLocationFiltered)

data = df.rdd
dataFilter = dfFilter.rdd

filteredResult = data.filter(lambda row: row.Time > '07:00' and row.Time < '17:00')
filteredResultExpected =dataFilter.filter(lambda row: row.Time > '07:00' and row.Time < '17:00')

print filteredResult.count()
print filteredResultExpected.count()
```

**filteredResultExpected =** and **filteredResult** was missing!